# How to repair a broken-resized qcow2 disk image for libvirt/kvm?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu, corruption, qcow2

Today I wanted to increase the size of a VM, so I did what I always do (have done it before):

```
qemu-img resize diskimage.qcow2 +22GB
```

Then the file broke and the VM does not start any more. I tried booting the VM from CD to adjust partitioning but the system will not read the disk any more:

```
qemu-img check -r all diskimage.qcow2
tcmalloc: large alloc 389841715200 bytes == (nil) @  0x7fdb4ea66bf3 0x7fdb4ea88488 0x7fdb4e5674a6 0x7fdb50236a37 0x7fdb50236bc8 0x7fdb50237011 0x7fdb5023941e 0x7fdb5023d891 0x7fdb5027848b 0x7fdb5027c196 0x7fdb491efb35 0x7fdb5021ee4d (nil)
No errors were found on the image.
```

No errors? Sounds good, but `virsh start vm` does not work and the logs say:

```
2017-05-21T10:02:30.755824Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/.../diskimage.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0: could not open disk image /.../diskimage.qcow2: qcow2: Image is corrupt; cannot be opened read/write
```

I tried converting to raw but the conversion fails (exit 1):

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 diskimage.qcow2 -O raw diskimage.raw
qcow2: Image is corrupt: L2 table offset 0x2d623039326500 unaligned (L1 index: 0); further non-fatal corruption events will be suppressed
qemu-img: error while reading block status of sector 0: Input/output error
```

The process creates a 354334801920 byte file (much larger than it should have been with +22GB) but it is apparently unusable - when I try to convert it back to qcow2 I get a 200kB file.

Is there a way to extract data from the qcow2 file, or mount it read-write somehow even if there is corruption? I do not have the `nbd` kernel module on the machine.

Comment: What host OS and libvirt version are you using?

Comment: Host and guest are CentOS 7, qemu-system-x86-2.0.0-1.el7.6.x86_64 and libvirt-2.0.0-10.el7_3.9.x86_64.

Answer (score 4):

Did you run the "qemu-img resize diskimage.qcow2 +22GB"  while the QEMU process was still running with the same disk open ?  If so, that would certainly explain the data corruption, as you would potentially have 2 processes writing to the qcow2 file at the same time and if both writes required qcow2 metadata allocations that could corrupt internal file data structures.

The "qemu-img check" result looks very bogus. In particular tcmalloc is complaining that it can't allocate a 360 GB block of memory. It looks like qemu-img is misinterpreting this error as success, printing the bogus message "No errors found". This is a bug you should certainly report to QEMU.

The 'convert' error just looks to be a followup to the same error that tcmalloc hit.

Unfortunately I don't have any suggestions to fix the problem - I was just going to recommend "check -r" to try to fix it. Your only likely remaining chance is to mail qemu-devel and see if any of the qcow2 maintainers have suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. I issued the resize after `virsh shutdown vm` but thinking back, if it took a long time it may still have been running. Of course that was unwise but ought not result in a full loss of 150GB of data?! Thanks for the recommendation with the mailing list, I might just do that.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  Not that I want to blame anyone but myself, but I'd assumed that it would have no problems resizing while the image was in use - or perhaps that it would abort with an error.  It barely occured to me that it might cause immediate disk corruption.

Comment: Note that current QEMU releases now have built-in protection for qcow2 file format. It will acquire locks on the file in an attempt to prevent users shooting themselves in the foot like this.

Answer (score 2):

Treat qcow2 corruption like a hard drive with bad blocks.

Shutdown that VM.

Then do:

```
modprobe nbd
qemu-nbd --connect=/dev/nbd0 diskimage.qcow2
ddrescue /dev/nbd0 new_diskimage.raw
qemu-nbd --disconnect /dev/nbd0
qemu-img convert -O qcow2 new_diskimage.raw new_diskimage.qcow2
```

Now try to boot and pray, hopefully it will get you to the rescue mode, where you can run fsck on that disk.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that, but `qemu-nbd` fails: `qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd1 /my/diskimage.qcow2` yields `Failed to blk_new_open '/my/diskimage.qcow2': qcow2: Image is corrupt; cannot be opened read/write` :-(  In fact, it cannot be opened, period. I would settle for read-only! (`-r` does not complain, but no partition table can be found).